# Gratis and GUI program to create separate compressed file archives (e.g., .zip or .7z) for each selected file/directory

Tags: windows, gratis, gui, file-compression

I'm looking for a GUI, free program for Microsoft Windows 7 or 10 that can create separate compressed file archives (e.g., .zip or .7z) for each selected file/directory.

For example, if I select 10 files, then the program should create 10 file archives, each of them corresponding to one file.

---

- 7zip seems to only have this feature  through command line ([How do I create separate zip files for each selected file/directory in 7zip?](https://superuser.com/q/311937/116475))
- WinRAR and [Total Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Commander) have the feature but aren't free. WinRAR:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered suggesting this as a new feature - possibly in the fork at https://github.com/jinfeihan57/p7zip/issues?q=is%3Aissue

Comment: @SteveBarnes thanks good point I haven't, I was instead hoping there was some already existing solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PeaZip](https://peazip.github.io) has the functionality you are looking for.
[image]

Here is more information about this feature https://peazip.github.io/how-to-zip-files-separate-archives.html

Specifically there is written:

> Compressing to distinct archives at once is possible when working with
> following archive types as output format: 7Z, ARC, PAQ, PEA, RAR, TAR,
> WIM, ZIP. All of these formats allows to create separate archives, a
> single archive for each input item

It is a program that has GUI, is Open-Source and supports multiple compression formats for both opening and archiving, including the powerful PAQ format.
It also has included several other useful tools such as calculating checksums, merging and splitting files, securely deleting files and more.